# How do we solve the integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}+x}{2-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve this irrational integral $$ \int \frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}+x}{2-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\, dx$$
doing the substitution

$$ x= \frac{2t^2}{1+ t^2}$$

So $dx=\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$

and the integral becomes:

$$  \int \frac{4t^2(1+t)}{(1+t^2)^2(t^2-t+1)}\, dt$$

According to the bood ot should be

$$  \int \frac{4t^2(1+t)}{(1+t^2)^2(t-1)^2}\, dt$$

As usual I have checked my calculation but I don't understand where I'm making mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct.
$$2x-x^2=1-(x-1)^2$$

$$x-1=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$$

$$1-(x-1)^2=\frac{t^4+2t^2+1-t^4+2t^2-1}{(t^2+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{4t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$
So it becomes
$$\int \frac{2t+2t^2}{2(t^2+1-t)}\frac{4tdt}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

You can compute this integral by putting
$$x-1=\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Here I propose another way to solve it for the sake of curiosity.

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{2x - x^{2}} + x}{2 - \sqrt{2x -x^{2}}} & = -1 + \frac{2 + x}{2 - \sqrt{2x - x^{2}}}\\\\
& = -1 - \frac{1 - x}{2 - \sqrt{2x - x^{2}}} + \frac{3}{2 - \sqrt{2x - x^{2}}}\\\\
& = -1 - \frac{1 - x}{2 - \sqrt{2x - x^{2}}} + \frac{3}{2 - \sqrt{1 - (1-x)^{2}}}
\end{align*}

To integrate the second term, you can make the substitution $u = 2x - x^{2}$.

To integrate the third term, you can make the substitution $\sin(\theta) = 1 - x$.

Can you take it from here?